# How do I display a link in a panel on my Firefox Extension using the Add-on SDK?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm currently making a Firefox extension using the Add-on SDK (widget).

What I'm trying to do upon the widget being clicked is:  Identify all addresses on a webpage,  highlight the addresses, and show a panel (attached to the widget) with links to Google Maps with the address.

The issue I am having is displaying a link in the panel.  I have been able to open and display actual sites and HTML files in the panel, but would like to know how, if possible, to display a clickable link in the panel.

I have been all over the Panel API and have not personally discovered a way.

Any tips are appreciated.  Thank you.

Edit:  I am using add-on sdk version 1.13.2

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a local file like `myFile.html` placed in your `data` directory.  From that file you can receive the port message show in the `onClick` function of the widget.

```
var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  contentURL: require("sdk/self").data.url("myFile.html");
});

require("sdk/widget").Widget({
  id: "addrs",
  label: "Addresses",
  contentURL: "https://maps.gstatic.com/favicon3.ico",
  panel: panel,
  onClick: function() {
    panel.port.emit('addrs', arrayOfAddresses);
  }

});
```

Read the [Getting User Input](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/panel.html#Getting%20User%20Input) section of the Panel docs for more info on structure of files and the code for myFile.html.