# Display a new html/web page in panel

Tags: html, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an addon for firefox using addon-SDK method. I would like to know if there is anyway to change the html(contentURL) displayed in that panel to a new webpage upon clicking a link in that contentURL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may need to visit [ask] for suggestions on how to improve your question and avoid getting down-voted.

Comment: @Ochi it's a good question. Vignesh yes there is a way. I did it long ago but ive been out of the sdk loop, so there may be a recommended way some sdk devs can share with you.

Comment: perhaps this can help answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073930/how-do-i-display-a-link-in-a-panel-on-my-firefox-extension-using-the-add-on-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vignesh here's code that receives the url clicked on:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#Scripting_panel_content

```
var myScript = "window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {" +
               "  var t = event.target;" +
               "  if (t.nodeName == 'A')" +
               "    self.port.emit('click-link', t.toString());" +
               "}, false);"

var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  contentURL: "http://www.bbc.co.uk/mobile/index.html",
  contentScript: myScript
});

panel.port.on("click-link", function(url) {
  console.log(url);
});

panel.show();
```

So then you can change that to be instead of console.log(url) you can make it find your panel and changes its iframes location to that url. Im not sure how to do this with sdk methods, maybe someone else can share. I would try to do this though:

```
panel.port.on("click-link", function(url) {
  panel.contentURL = url;
});
```

edit:
`panel.contentURL = url` may not work so you have to do it like this:

```
const { getMostRecentBrowserWindow } = require('sdk/window/utils');
var aXULBrowser = getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
aXULBrowser.getElementById('ID OF YOUR PANEL, probably same as id to your widget here').getElementsByTagName('iframe').contentWindow.location = url;
```

Comment: @Vignesh if `panel.contentURL = url` doesn't work then you can do what I added above. If you can't figure out the id of your panel use DOM Insepctor and Elment Inspector addons then shift+right click your panel and it will open it up in the inspector, you can then easily see the panel id.